# Why the variable in shell script from the result of python works strange?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am trying to get a variable in bash shell from the result of python.
Here is my python code:

```
print '** it is python testing **'
```

And I made a shell script. When I make it normally, it shows very correct result.

```
#!/bin/bash
python pytest.py
```

Result : 
`** it is python testing **`

But, when I made it as a variable in shell, it showed strange result.
Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#python pytest.py

PYTEST="$(python pytest.py)"
echo $PYTEST
```

Then the result is seem like this:

`ptest.sh pytest.py it is python testing ptest.sh pytest.py`

I tried it from other complicate code, but result is almost same. The variable in shell script always shows some files in directory. I'm not good at shell script but can't understand why.
(I'm using GNU bash, 4.1.10 version)

Does anyone can help me?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: a wild guess: `echo "$PYTEST"` needs to enclose the string in quotes

Comment: @Pavel might be right. You're definitely triggering shell expansion somewhere; I'm just not sure if it's in the `echo` or the variable set. The `**` are being converted to the file paths the shell can find.

Comment: Damn you're right!! I was terribly bad at shell script. Thanks Pavel!

Comment: On a different note (or as an aside) -- shell variables which are neither exported to the environment or shell builtins should be all-lowercase, to avoid shadowing, overriding, being overwritten by, or otherwise interfering with environment variables by mistake. So this should probably be `pytest=$(...)` rather than `PYTEST=$(...)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't quote your expansions, they're string-split and glob-expanded. "Glob expansion" means that things like `*` get changed to lists of filenames.

So, quoting:

```
echo "$PYTEST"
```

...will pass the exact output as a single string.

Not quoting:

```
echo $PYTEST
```

...will first expand:

```
echo ** it is python testing **
```

...and then will change the `**`s to lists of filenames, and *then* invoke `echo`.

---

Note that the string splitting can have unexpected effects even without globbing. Let's say that your Python program did this:

```
print "      it is python testing"
```

You might expect `echo $PYTEST` to work fine in that case... but instead, you'll see that it drops the leading whitespace:

```
> echo $PYTEST
it is python testing
```

Why? Because string-splitting breaks the input down into words, and passes each word as a separate argument to echo, and echo joins its arguments with one space between each.

So, just as the following drops whitespace:

```
> echo       it is     python testing
it is python testing
```

...the same is also true with unquoted expansions in POSIX-compliant shells. (zsh, by the way, does *not* comply with POSIX in this respect, and implicitly treats expansions as if they were quoted).